# Adding Two Power Series if their bounds are different

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the following product

$$\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-x}{2}\right)^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_nx^{n+2}}{n!}$$

Where $a_n$ is an arbitrary coefficient.  If I factor out $x^2$ from the second power series i can rewrite as a Cauchy Product

$$\frac{x^2}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^ka_{n-k}}{2^k(n-k)!}x^n$$
Now this becomes
$$\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^ka_{n-k}}{2^k(n-k)!}x^{n+2}$$

But I'm confused how to reindex the convolution

Is the reindexed summation

$$\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^ka_{n-k}}{2^{k-2}(n-k)!}x^n$$

EDIT:
There is a bigger picture to this problem.  I have the following that I want to combine as a single sum somehow (pardon the pun):

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}-\frac{1}{6(1+\frac{x}{2})} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_nx^{n+2}}{n!}   $$

I know that I can rewrite the first fraction $\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}}$ as $\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{2}}$ which can be rewritten as a power series 
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{2^n}$$

Rewriting the difference and taking Cauchy Product of both terms yields

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{2^n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{2^n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_nx^{n+2}}{n!}   $$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^ka_{n-k}}{2^k(n-k)!}x^n-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kb_{n-k}}{2^k(n-k)!}x^{n+2}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^ka_{n-k}}{2^k(n-k)!}x^n-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kb_{n-k}}{2^{k-2}(n-k)!}x^n$$
How do I procede from there?

Comment: In your "Is the reindexed summation", you have an $x^k$ that ought to be an $x^n$. Just a typo, presumably. Apart from that, it's correct.

Comment: Will fix that in a second.  I was considering trying to  perhaps extract the first two terms from the left hand side term and combining from there.  Is there a better method?

Comment: I don't think so, and in the combined series, you also have the unpleasantness that the coefficient-convolution from the first series starts at $k = 0$, and from the second at $k = 2$, which means you can't _nicely_ combine them (without introducing a special symbol or so).

Comment: Although, if you like Iverson brackets, it's not bad.

Comment: And in the very last sum, it's $b_{n-k}$, not $a_{n-k}$.

Comment: What is an Iverson bracket?  I cut and pasted from above with the $a_n$,... ha ha

Comment: So basically I could say that the expression equals $0$ if $n<k$?  Similar to a kronecker delta function?

Comment: I guessed you copy-pasted and forgot to change. An Iverson bracket is similar to a Kronecker-$\delta$, but more general. $[P]$ is $1$ if $P$ is true, and $0$ otherwise, so we have $\delta_{ab} = [a = b]$. Here we'd use $[n \geqslant 2]$ and $[k\geqslant 2]$.

Comment: How does that look in the summation?  How do I apply it notationally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reindexed summation is correct. Since the sums (outer and inner) for the second series start at $n = 2$ resp. $k = 2$ while in the first they start at $0$, combining the two power series is not totally direct. One way is to split the sums, treat $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ separately, and in the remaining series, for the inner sum $k = 0$ and $k = 1$. A more compact notation can be obtained using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket),

$$[P] = \begin{cases} 1 &, P\text{ is true}\\ 0 &, \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Then we can write the second series

$$\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \Biggl(\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(-1)^k b_{n-k}}{2^{k-2}(n-k)!}\Biggr)x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty [n\geqslant 2]\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{[k\geqslant 2]2(-1)^kb_{n-k}}{2\cdot 2^k(n-k)!}\Biggr)x^n$$

and combine as

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k(n-k)!}\biggl(a_{n-k} - \frac{2}{3}[n\geqslant 2][k\geqslant 2] b_{n-k}\biggr)\Biggr)x^n.$$

Since we have $k\leqslant n$, the condition $n \geqslant 2$ is implied by $k\geqslant 2$, hence redundant, and we can further simplify to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k(n-k)!}\biggl(a_{n-k} - \frac{2}{3}[k\geqslant 2] b_{n-k}\biggr)\Biggr)x^n.$$